# How to add a physical keyboard layout

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, external-keyboard

I'm using a Logitech Tablet Keyboard for Android with Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.1).

When I go to Settings -> Language & input -> Physical Keyboard and tap on Logitech Tablet Keyboard Gen there is an option to "Set up keyboard layouts". There are many predefined layouts but the "Polish (programmer)" keyboard layout is missing. How can I add one?

I have looked at /system/usr/keylayout and /system/usr/keychars but I don't see the other layouts there.

I know there is an app that does not require root, but it's aa virtual keyboard that works with bluetooth keyboards https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper and I'm interested only in adding the layout to the built-in physical keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite an easy task. See the source of the InputDevices system package. Or get the ready to use Polish programmers external keyboard layout plugin from there: https://sites.google.com/site/polishhardwarekbd/

You'll find the app source there as well. Regards.

Comment: Awesome, it worked like a charm! Thanks for that link.

Answer (score 3):

You should install extra keyboard layouts:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=varzan.extraKeyboardLayouts
.

It is free and helps me to type on Mongolian language and included many other languages.

Comment: Thank you sir..

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in this too.

However, as a temporary fix I found that the soft keyboard you have selected seems to affect the way a bluetooth keyboard functions. For example:

I usually use Go! Keyboard. While I have this selected my shift key is a latch (double press for shift-lock) and ctrl-c and ctrl-v do not function. However, when I switch to Hacker's Keyboard, shift requires me to hold it down and ctrl-c, -v and -a all work as they would on  a PC.

What I would really like to do is edit the way the fn- functions or some of the iphone of mac keys work to attatch them to my back, recents and menu buttons. This must be possible because one of the keys already works as 'home.'

Comment: Interesting. If you pull the notifications and click on Input Method there is a physical keyboard turned on but the soft IME is selected too. I'm using Swype and CTRL+C/V/X are working correctly when editing a large portion of text (for example in Writer) but those hot keys are broken in Internet application's address bar (I suppose the keys are intercepted).