# Is there a way to input a specific language with keyboard that is not supported by the android

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, languages

I'm using `Mi 4i` and I wanted to input Thai by using a bluetooth keyboard `logitech K480`.

I couldn't find out how to input by Thai and asked support center of `Xiaomi`.
The clerk said that the input Thai with bluetooth keyboard is not supported by `Mi 4i`.

Is there a way to "activate" or make it possible to input Thai with keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [External Keyboard Helper Demo from Apedroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo) (full version [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper)). It says in the description it supports Thai keyboards.

Also, check out [this thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30256/how-to-add-a-physical-keyboard-layout)